# How does this Padding Function work

Tags: python, aes, padding

I use a Padding function:

```
def _pad(self, s):
    return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

def _unpad(self, s):
    return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

Due to a certain lack of syntax and modulo skills here, I don't see through this. Is this bet practice for padding and unpadding messages for AES CBC en/decryption? Or would you recommend a different function?

self.bs is the blocksize, which is 32 by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part of the functions you show is that they encode the amount of padding being applied in the ASCII value of the padding character using `chr` and `ord` to encode and decode the value, respectively. That's pretty clever. It does require that all strings be padded though, even ones who's lengths were already exact multiples of `self.bs`.

Here's a clearer version of the two functions, which has the different steps explicitly split out:

```
def _pad(self, s):
    amount_of_padding = self.bs - len(s) % self.bs   # between 1 and self.bs, inclusive
    padding_char = chr(amount_of_padding)            # encode amount_of_padding in ASCII!
    return s + amount_of_padding * padding_char      # do string repetition with *

def _unpad(self, s):
    padding_char = s[-1]                     # last char is always part of the padding
    amount_of_padding = ord(padding_char)    # decode amount from ASCII value of char
    return s[:-amount_of_padding]            # slice to skip padding chars
```

The only odd thing in the original code is in `_unpad` where they use of `s[len(s)-1]` rather than  `s[-1]`. I don't see any reason for that, since the two expressions do exactly the same thing (get the last character).